# Is the definition of a transcendental field extension necessarily impredicative?

Tags: logic, field-theory, transcendental-numbers

Let $t$ be transcendental over $K$, i.e. there is no $p(x) \in K[x]$ s.t. $p(t)=0$.

Can you define the smallest field containing $K$ and $t$ in a predicative way? If not, how would you prove that this is not possible?

The first definition coming to my mind is $K(t):= \bigcap_{K\subseteq L, t \in L } {L}$, with $L$ being a field. In this case, one of the fields $L$ must exactly be the object we are defining, thus making the definition impredicative.

Remark: the problem does not arise for the case of algebraic extensions.
Given $a$ algebraic over $K$ with minimal polynomial $m_a(x) \in K[x]$, I thought about defining $K(a):= K[x]/(m_a(x))$, which is predicative. It's easy to show that this is a field containing $a$ and $K$, and a copy of $K(a):= K[x]/(m_a(x))$ can be embedded in any field containing $a$ and $K$, thus making $K[x]/(m_a(x))$ a good definition capturing "the smallest field containing $K$ and $a$".

Comment: I thought that the definition as the fraction field of $K[t]$ (all polynomials with variable $t$) would be the predicative one?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: thank you! Are you aware of definitions that cannot be turned into predicative ones (and of proof techniques for showing results of the like)?

Comment: I am not particularly versed in impredicativity. I'm not even sure that the fraction field is impredicative (but it seems to me that it is). Generally, I'd say, if you have a definable function that applying it once produces the wanted structure, you should be able to do it in a non-predicative way. But again, I am not an expert on this topic.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I am quite confident that frac$(K[t])$ is predicative. It is, by definition, a field. Clearly, it contains $t$ and $K$. Moreover, for any field $L$ containing $K$ and $t$, it can be shown that there is an injection of frac$(K[t])$ into $L$, which captures the fact that frac$(K[t])$ is the smallest field containing $K$ and $t$. The fact that $t$ is transcendental is used to prove the injection of frac$(K[t])$ into $L$.

Comment: I think Asaf's comment may have led in a wrong direction: when you say "let $t$ be transcendental over $K$", you are implicitly assuming that $t$ belongs to some superfield $L \supseteq K$ in which $t$ resides and in which it makes sense to say that $t$ is not the root of any $p \in K[x]$. So there is no question of impredicativity in defining the smallest subfield of $L$ that contains $K$ and $t$, as this only requires quantification over the (implicitly) given field $L$.